# Rotating Y changes X value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm clamping an animation in LateUpdate:

```
    float fMinRotationLR = 320f;

    float fOldX = Chest.localEulerAngles.x;

    if (Chest.localRotation.eulerAngles.y < fMinRotationLR)
    {
         Chest.Rotate(new Vector3(Chest.localRotation.x, fMinRotationLR, Chest.localRotation.z));
    }

    float fNewX = Chest.localEulerAngles.x;
```

Before the call to "Rotate", fOldX is 23, after the call to "Rotate", fNewX is 0.

What is happening here and how would I prevent this?

I have already tried using

```
Chest.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(Chest.localRotation.x, fMinRotationLR, Chest.localRotation.z);
```

but that gives the same result.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transform.Rotate(x,y,z)` or its equivalent that accept `Vector3` will, well, rotate the transform by x degree around the x axis, y degree around the y axis, etc. So your original code:

```
Chest.Rotate(new Vector3(Chest.localRotation.x, fMinRotationLR, Chest.localRotation.z));
```

will rotate the Chest `Chest.localRotation.x` degrees around the x axis, which is just enough to bring it back to 0.

To dig a bit deeper, software convention state that a function/method usually mean "an action that *does* something". A method named `SetRotation` is usually equal to `rotation =`.

In this case the method name is `Rotate` so by the same convention we could deduce that it means "rotate the transform by". Unity's API adhere to this convention pretty well.

Your second attempt:

```
Chest.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(Chest.localRotation.x, fMinRotationLR, Chest.localRotation.z);
```

also doesn't work, because your are assigning Chest.localRotation's value (which is a [Quaternion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)) to Chest.localEulerAngles (which is a Vector3). Quaternion is a Vector4, and is another method (more reliable) to represent 3D rotational state. It is different from the EulerAngles, so the values doesn't have the same meaning.

You seem to have fixed the issue yourself, I'm only explaining why it happens.

```
Chest.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(Chest.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, fMinRotationLR, Chest.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please include my solution in your answer for completeness? I guess that else readers might get confused what actually worked. Thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

I got it!!! :-)

```
            Chest.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(Chest.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, fMinRotationLR, Chest.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);
```

Comment: Rather than "I got it", you should explain the change you made so others can understand what's going on